# Rails 3.1.1 has_secure_password digest can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have been playing around with has_secure_password and I ran into a problem. My test for the create action in my UsersController was not <strike>working</strike> passing. So I started playing around in the console and realized that the password was not being converted to a has and saved in password_digest field.

When I try to create a user from the console the following happens.

```
irb(main):031:0> u = User.new(:email => "test1@test.com", :password => "test", :password_confirmation => "test")
=> #<User id: nil, email: "test1@test.com", password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):032:0> u.save
=> false
irb(main):033:0> u.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000100cde500 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "test1@test.com", password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:password_digest=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. It looks like the password_digest attribute never gets assigned. If I create a user object with no attributes and assign each attribute individually I get the same error.

Here is my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
end
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Alex Shenoy

Answer (score 10):

I had the same symptom, a message that the password_digest cannot be blank. The problem I had was that I had set this in the user.rb:

```
  attr_accessor :password
```

This prevented the method password= from being called (see secure_password.rb)

```
  # Encrypts the password into the password_digest attribute.
  def password=(unencrypted_password)
    @password = unencrypted_password
    unless unencrypted_password.blank?
      self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(unencrypted_password)
    end
  end
```

and thus the value was never set for the password_digest.

For me, the fix was to remove the attr_accessor line.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem. Mine would save the user, but `password_digest` was always `nil`. For me it was because I had the following code order in my model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation
has_secure_password
```

I changed it to:

```
has_secure_password
attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple example and worked as expected. Maybe you have something in your config that is messing with this. My simple test:

```
$ rails new test
$ cd test
$ rails g model user name:string password_digest:string
$ rake db:migrate
$ vim app/model/user.rb
```

add

```
has_secure_password
attr_accessible :name, :password, :password_confirmation
```

save and exit

```
$ rails c

Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.1)
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :001 > u = User.new(:name => "test1@test.com", :password => "test", :password_confirmation => "test")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "test1@test.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$08xY7p.8hq1.95ZQsx63ku05YfvVqSQ/CLiqUW5dtGhZ...", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > u.save
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
  SQL (51.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "name", "password_digest", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sun, 23 Oct 2011 13:38:49 UTC +00:00], ["name", "test1@test.com"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$08xY7p.8hq1.95ZQsx63ku05YfvVqSQ/CLiqUW5dtGhZSP9S7FtUy"], ["updated_at", Sun, 23 Oct 2011 13:38:49 UTC +00:00]]
=> true
```